# python convert ISO 8601 time doesn't work

Tags: python, iso8601

I'm trying to convert dates from the utcnow (ISO 8601) function of azure logics apps in python:

this one returns the following format:

```
2018-02-07T13:30:17.2967490Z
```

so I'm doing it:

```
dateformat = datetime.strptime ("2018-02-07T13:30:17.2967490Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

but it doesn't work, do you have any idea?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Also, what's with the spaces between hours, minutes and seconds…?!

Answer (score 2):

You have spaces in your format. And after your microseconds (6 digits), you for some reason have the characters `0Z`. So you could use this:

```
"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f0Z"
```

As in:

```
>>> datetime.strptime ("2018-02-07T13:30:17.2967490Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f0Z")
datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 7, 13, 30, 17, 296749)
```

Comment: Hello thank you space just come from my cut and paste sorry
will it also work for a date in this format? 
2018-02-07T15:41:49.7447688Z

Comment: Where are you getting these weirdly formatted dates?

Comment: from the utcnow() function from azure logic apps see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language

Comment: The python microsecond field only accepts 6 digits. The ISO8601 standard (as I read it) specifies at most 6 digits. So I don't know what reason there is for having 7 digits.

Comment: Do you have any solution for that  ? the picture : https://ibb.co/ccRF8H